# Calculating probability for FUNPROB

Tags: c++, math, probability

Regarding - 
[FUNPROB](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FUNPROB/)

The solution is :

```
int N, M;
while(1) {
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
    if (0 == N && 0 == M) break;

    if (N > M) printf("0.000000\n");
    else {
        double res = (double) (M-N+1) / (M+1);
        printf("%.6f\n", res);
    }   
}
```

My question is regarding line

```
res = (M-N+1) / (M+1);
```

How to arrive at the conclusion that the probability is calculated in this way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer.
The problem keywords are Dyck words and Catalan number. @Ali's answer is the proof that answer is correct but doesnt explain how we arrive at the number.

1. Realise that if M < N, probability is 0.
2. If M >= N, its a necessary condition for having change but not sufficient. You need to have the correct order of people in queue. For eg. M=3, N=2  MMMNN is correct while NNMMM is not correct. So we have to filter out incorrect possible queues.

The problem can be thought of in terms of paths that go up/down in one time step. X axis is time axis, +Y axis is M and -Y axis is N.
If we start from (0, 0) traverse up 1 unit for each M and -1 unit for each N then we **always** end up at (M+N, M-N).

Our answer is: (Total number of paths from (0, 0) to (M+N, M-N) - Paths which go below X axis at least once) / Total number of paths.

[image]

Solving for above gives answer as (M-N+1)/(M+1).

*The second term in numerator comes using reflection principle. If you want more details, add a comment and I will update the answer.

for the last part https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed

Answer (score 7):

At first it is obvious that if `N>M` probability is zero.

now I want to use indication on `N` to prove. consider `M>0` I want to prove for every `N=<M` we have  `res = (M-N+1) / (M+1)` for `N=0` it is obvious that probability is `1`.

For `N=1` put every body we `5$` in a queue in arbitrary order, now for the one person with `10$` you could put him every where except in front of the queue so you have between `M+1` places that are available you have `M+1-1` choices. so for `N=1` you have : `res = (M-1+1) / (M+1)`

suppose formula is correct for every `N=<k` I want to prove that if `N=k+1` formula is still correct. for that put `M` people with `5$` and `k` people with 10$ in a arbitrary queue. we suppose that `res = (M-K+1) / (M+1)` is the probability of working this queue and every body could have his ticket. consider one of the working queues in this queue if a `10$` person is behind `5$` person remove both of them and do this recursively until there is no `5$` person. this will work because as I said above the first person of the queue is a `10$` one, and also I said that `N<M` the probability of putting the `K+1` person in the queue is choosing one place among `M-k+1` because we remove `k` `10$` person from the queue. and it is like what we said for `N=1` so we have probability of putting `K+1`th `5$` person in the queue is : `((M-k) - 1 +1) / ((M - k) +1)`(*) and by indication we have that probability of a working queue for `N=k` is : `(M-k +1) / (M +1)`( * *) from (*) and ( * *) we have probability of putting `K+1` people with `10$` and `M` people with `5$` in a queue with questions condition is :

> [((M-k) - 1 +1) / ((M - k) +1)] * [(M-k +1) / (M +1)] = ((M-k) - 1 +1) / (M +1) = (M-(k+1) +1) / (M +1)

And it is end of the proof :).

Comment: your answer doesnt explain how to arrive the final term, see my answer  for answer I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: @hack3r in fact it does explain. In about 20 lines I try to explain it, if you dont understand something you could simply ask what part you dont understand, not after several month say that it is not what your are looking for!